# Pegar arquivo PHP com variáveis GET

Tags: php

Boa tarde. Vou utilizar o PHPMailer, mas não estou sabendo fazer o envio utilizando variáveis.

Veja:

```
$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
$mail->IsHTML(true);    
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('proposta.php?id='.$_GET["id"].''), dirname(__FILE__));
```

Preciso que o arquivo `proposta.php` receba o ID da proposta.

Erro:

> Warning: file_get_contents(proposta.php?id=17):
>   failed to open stream: Resource temporarily unavailable

Como é possível fazer isso?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, pois o problema não é com o phpmailer

Answer (score 1):

Não mander `file_get_content()` ler o seu arquivo, peça para ele fazer uma requisição ou seja adicione o protocolo e a url completa.

torque:

```
file_get_contents('proposta.php?id='.$_GET["id"].''
```

Por:

```
file_get_contents('http://localhost/projeto/ proposta.php?id='.$_GET["id"].''
```